# Changing Content in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton

Looking for the best approach:
I have a tabbar and a navigationbar. under the navigationbar I put three buttons.
One for the projekt description, the next should show the project schedule and the third the project tasks.
Below the buttons I have a scrollview for the content.
What would be the best way to switch/change the content of the scrollview depending on, which button was used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would build 3 different views, when the buttons tapped clear the scrollview then add the new view to the scroll view, then adjust the scrollview's content size.

Answer (score 0):

UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView and thus automatically implements scrolling behaviour. You can use the text property to set the text shown.

If what you want to show is not only textual, you can create a custom view programmatically (or by loading it from a NIB) and put it in the UIScrollView whenever a button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `scrollRectToVisible`, something like this:

```
 -(void)scrollToIndex(UIButton*)sender{

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSInteger *index = btn.tag;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.contentScrollView.frame)*index, 0,    CGRectGetWidth(self.contentScrollView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.contentScrollView.frame));
    [self.contentScrollView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES];

}
```

}

Now, it os good to handle an other option if the user wants to manually scroll the view:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    // Switch the currentDataView when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
    CGFloat pageWidth = sender.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((sender.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    pageControl.currentPage = page;

   //You can also set the highlight of the button that relate to this view
}
```